# CNAME not resolving with nslookup, but dig works

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-s3

I am trying to point a CNAME to a S3 bucket, but keep having problems with the CNAME not being found by `nslookup` (and by my browser, for that matter).

When I use `dig` however, it shows me the correct output for the domain. I'm fairly certain that i'm missing something stupid here but I can't seem to find the problem :(

Any help is appreciated!

```
➜  ~  nslookup img.springe.st
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find img.springe.st: NXDOMAIN

➜  ~  dig img.springe.st

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> img.springe.st
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 8429
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;img.springe.st.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
img.springe.st.     1800    IN  CNAME   imgs3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
amazonaws.com.      5   IN  SOA pdns1.ultradns.net. hostmaster.amazon.com. 2013111100 180 60 2592000 5

;; Query time: 55 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Nov 18 15:47:10 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 155
```

Comment: Go into the console and get the *actual* subdomain. It'll be something like `imgs3-website.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`. Also, consider using Route53 to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the Google DNS won't resolve your CNAME as the hostname it is pointing to is not resolvable itself:

```
# nslookup imgs3-website-eu-west-1-amazonaws.com 8.8.8.8
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find imgs3-website-eu-west-1-amazonaws.com: NXDOMAIN
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it because the hostname the CNAME points to doesn't exist?

```
dig imgs3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;imgs3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com. IN A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
amazonaws.com.      5   IN  SOA dns-external-master.amazon.com. hostmaster.amazon.com. 2012091400 180 60 2592000 5
```

Answer (score 1):

imgs3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com can not be resolved... So that makes the CNAME record somewhat invalid

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the nic.st interface translates `img.springe.st.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` to `imgs3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com.` somehow. I missed that when adding the DNS entry. Thanks for pointing out to me that the domain the cname refers to actually has to exists for it to resolve!